# boost::future - Is wait_callback guaranteed to only be invoked once?

Tags: c++, boost-thread, future

If I set a `set_wait_callback` on a `boost::unique_future`, is it guaranteed to only run once?

I'm a bit suspicious since when looking at the source code I find the following:

```
struct relocker
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock;

    relocker(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock_):
        lock(lock_)
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    ~relocker()
    {
        lock.lock();
    }
private:
    relocker& operator=(relocker const&);
};

void do_callback(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)
{
    if(callback && !done)
    {
        boost::function<void()> local_callback=callback;
        relocker relock(lock); // unlock mutex?
        local_callback();
    }
}    

void wait(bool rethrow=true)
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
    do_callback(lock);
    while(!done)
    {
        waiters.wait(lock);
    }
    if(rethrow && exception)
    {
        boost::rethrow_exception(exception);
    }
}
```

Where in `do_callback` the mutex is actually unlocked while the callback is invoked, which from my understanding can lead to the callback being called multiple times if multiple threads call the `wait` function?

Can the callback be called multiple times? Is it by design? Or am I missing something?

The reason I'm a bit surprised is that in the C++11 standard the `async(std::launch::deferred, ...)` (to which `set_wait_callback` is a cousin), seems to have single invocation guarantee:

§30.6.8

> The shared state is not made ready until the function has completed.
>   **The first call** to a non-timed waiting function (30.6.4) on an
>   asynchronous return object referring to this shared state **shall invoke
>   the deferred function in the thread that called the waiting function**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suspicion is founded. The code should look like

```
void do_callback(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)
{
    if(callback && !done)
    {
        boost::function<void()> local_callback=callback;
        callback=boost::function<void()>;
        relocker relock(lock); // unlock mutex?
        local_callback();
    }
}
```

or even

```
void do_callback(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)
{
    if(callback && !done)
    {
        boost::function<void()> local_callback=boos::move(callback);
        relocker relock(lock); // unlock mutex?
        local_callback();
    }
}
```

once Boost.Function will support move semantics.

This has yet some issues as another thread could call set_wait_callback, so callback could be reassigned and two callbacks could be called. It seems that an additional state is needed to state if the callback has already been done.

```
void do_callback(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)
{
    if(callback && ! callback_done && !done)
    {
        boost::function<void()> local_callback=callback;
        callback_done=true;
        relocker relock(lock); // unlock mutex?
        local_callback();
    }
}
```

BTW, set_wait_callback is not thread-safe.

```
    template<typename F,typename U>
    void set_wait_callback(F f,U* u)
    {
        callback=boost::bind(f,boost::ref(*u));
    }
```

and must be protected

```
    template<typename F,typename U>
    void set_wait_callback(F f,U* u)
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        callback=boost::bind(f,boost::ref(*u));
    }
```

Please, could you create a Trac ticket to Boost Thread so this issue is not lost?

Comment: The issue is more complex than it seems at a first glance. From the documentation it seems that the callback should be called each time a wait function is called.
"Effects:
    Store a copy of f with the asynchronous result associated with *this as a wait callback. This will replace any existing wait callback store alongside that result. If a thread subsequently calls one of the wait functions on a future or boost::shared_future associated with this result, and the result is not ready, f(*this) shall be invoked."